# Accessible custom styled checkbox

Tags: html, accessibility

I'm using a label element to create a custom styled checkbox.
Essentially I'm using it as a button to later perform some styling with the :checked selector. I'm not submitting the value to a form.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="agree" style="display:none" />
.......
<!-- few more divs here -->
.......
<label for="agree" role="button">Click here</label>
<div>This div will be styled if the checkbox is ticked</div>
```

My question is, in accessibility point of view, is this correct?
Is there a more semantic way to do it? (css only must mention)

My need is a custom styled checkbox.

I think the correct semantic way will be using a `<button>`, but then it does not work as a label and will not tick the checkbox..

Comment: Why don't you want to use Jquery?

Comment: I'd prefer to avoid javascript whenever there's a way to do it with css only. Css is faster and more reliable.

Comment: Check this: [Radio-Controlled Web Design](http://alistapart.com/article/radio-controlled-web-design#section12), an excellent article about everything you need to know about the CSS Checkbox Hack, including a11y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer of @Adam, he linked to a resource [2.2 Second rule of ARIA use](https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#second) which gave me a good hint how to solve my problem.

Instead of doing this

`<label for="agree" role="button">Click here</label>`

The correct way will be

`<label for="agree"><span role="button">Click here</span></label>`

Since I cannot use a `<button>` (this will conflict with the label ticking the checkbox), I am using a span with `role="button"`.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to do this is to take profit of `aria-checked` and `role=checkbox` attributes, but this needs Javascript:

```
<label for="agree">Click here</label>
<div id="agree" role="checkbox" aria-checked="true" tabindex="0">
       This div will be styled if the checkbox is ticked</div>
```

The failures for accessibility in your examples are multiple:

- the label refers to a non accessible input which will prevent the assistive technology to see to the associated element
- the element is not operable using the keyboard
- You use a `role` attribute on a semantic element ["Do not change native semantics, unless you really have to."](https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#second)

Note, that you can perfectly use the standard `checkbox` element and apply some css on it without completely hiding it.

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="agree" value="1" />
    <div>I agree with the above elements</div>
</label>

-----
/* the input would be hidden but still focusable */
#agree {width: 0px; margin-left: 2px; overflow: hidden;}

/* when focusing the element, we will outline the text to make the focus visible */
#agree:focus + div {outline: dotted 2px blue}

/* default when unticked */
#agree + div {background-image: url("ko.png") no-repeat; border: solid transparent 2px;}

/* default when ticked */
#agree:checked + div {background-image: url("ok.png") no-repeat; border: solid green 2px;}
```

This requires that your CSS makes a visible difference not relying on the sole use of colors.

Comment: Based on the resource you linked about not changing native semantics, I got an idea how to get what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Only using CSS and HTML I may suggest the following solution:

```
<label for='checkbox'>
     <span style='cursor:pointer;border:1px solid red; background:yellow;padding:5px;border-radius:5px;'>Click</span>
</label>
<input id='checkbox' type='checkbox' />
```

So you don't need button. You may customize the span.

Check fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/an0tcLmc/

Comment: Thanks but I know how to style a checkbox this way, my question is about accessibility

Comment: What does it mean? You click on button and checkbox is checked/uncheked. You may make the checkbox hidden and use button.

Comment: I'm not using the checkbox in a form. I'm using a checkbox in order to benefit from the :checked selector later. The question is just if semantically this is correct. I know that <button> is more semantically correct for this use, but <button> cannot check/uncheck a checkbox (without js)

Comment: What means 'semanthically'? You may use wharever you want if it's good for you. If you don't want to use JS, you don't have a lot of choice.

Comment: HTML5 is all about semantics.. thank you friend, but I don't think you can help me in this question :)